# Emacs in Org mode, how to send file to specific program

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to make links and send, for example, a text file to Firefox sometimes and sometimes to Gedit.

How can I make a link to tell Firefox to open the file.

The system has to be versatile, since sometimes I send a .jpg to Firefox and sometimes I use another program, but it has to be linked as hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
(setq reverse-org-file-apps 
  '(("firefox %s" . "\\.\\(?:xhtml\\|html\\|txt\\|jpg\\|png\\)")
    ("gedit %s" . "\\(?:txt\\|cc\\)")
    ("evince \"%s\"" . "\\.pdf\\'") 
    ("okular \"%s\"" . "\\.pdf\\'")))

(defun new-org-open-at-point (program)
  (interactive
   (list 
    (completing-read "Open with: "
                     reverse-org-file-apps
                     nil t)))
  (let* ((chosen-program (assoc program reverse-org-file-apps))
         (org-file-apps (list (cons (cdr chosen-program) 
                                    (car chosen-program)))))
    (org-open-at-point)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'new-org-open-at-point)
```

Each time you invoke `new-org-open-at-point`, it'll give you
a completion minibuffer with possible applications.
You can extend `reverse-org-file-apps` as you like.

Answer (score 1):

How about the file openwith.el ?

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OpenWith

Comment: In the meantime, I found another solution: shell:firefox nameoffile does the trick. Other programs can be run a command + file name too.